# chrome os: crosh tab completion

Tags: shell, chrome-os

Tab-completion doesn't seem to work in crosh, or even in other Chrome OS apps - it kind of does what's expected, in that it tabs to the address bar, but unfortunately that's not what I want.

I could have sworn this worked when I tried it in a previous session. Is there a special switch or a key which will allow this? It makes using the shell a bit more challenging, and I'm sure it was working before...

Comment: Tab-completion is working with Page Up key.

Comment: There is no specific "page up" key on my Chromebook (Toshiba Chromebook 2), unfortunately.

I seem to have got it working - I think by installing a different shell (from the dev channel) that appears to capture the "Tab" key when pressed. I'm not sure exactly which for the moment, so I'll report back here when I find out.

Answer (score 0):

For the search key (left of a, in place of caps lock) now works as a tab autocomplete

Comment: To be exact: Search Key(left of "a") + Up or Down Arrow Keys.